# paintComponent method run inside of the JPanel constructor

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent

I'm new to the forum. This is actually my first post, and I'm still figuring things out. I recently started working on learning Java, and I have been working on the paintComponent method. I was looking up a way to paint to a panel that I constructed in the main method. I have done it the way that I have seen where you create a second class that extends JPanel, but I was curious if it can be done without extending JPanel, and completed entirely from the main class. I came across this post by SantaXL about 7 years ago, and it works beautifully, but I can't figure out why it works. I'm not even sure what to call the process to look it up. I would love to know why it's okay to run a method inside the main method if I do it inside the JPanel constructor in this way.

I appreciate any help you can give.

[Old Post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVeZN.png)

I just want to know why this works, and what this style is called.

Comment: *but I was curious if it can be done without extending JPanel,* - No. Custom painting is done by extending JPanel (or JComponent). If you want to change the painting on the panel then you need methods to change the data to be painted on the panel. Read the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information. *what this style is called.* - you are creating an annonymous inner class and overriding the paintComponent() method. If you look in your directory you will see a class file of the form "Yourclass$1.class".

Answer (score 1):

So essentially what's going on here is you are creating a new version of the `JPanel` class, without having to create a new class, extend the JPanel, and give it a name. I've added a bunch of notes to your code snippet below to hopefully walk you through what's happening.

```
//This first line creates a new instance, and with the boolean
//parameter, sets the BufferStrategy to double-buffered (important later,
//but for now just think of this as a good default).
JPanel panel = new JPanel(true) {
    //Here you're overriding a built-in method (paintComponent)in the JPanel class. 
    //Overriding it allows you to alter its default behavior. 
    //NOTE that this requires you to use the exact name of the built-in method.
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        //supering the paintComponent method with the Graphics object allows
        //the class to function as though you hadn't overridden this mathod,
        //which allows the background to be redrawn as it is supposed to, 
        //every frame. Removing this will cause issues when you try to animate
        //anything or change what is being painted to the panel. 
        super.paintComponent(g);
        //all your paint code would go here. 
    }
}
```

Typically this is called an anonymous inner class or a nested class. You can read more about them [here](https://www.programiz.com/java-programming/anonymous-class).